# How to stop IntelliJ IDEA from adding a close brace } immediately after I write a { open brace

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

When using IntelliJ IDEA, I write a { brace and immediately the IDE writes a close brace }.

This is more often annoying when I am editing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's `Settings -> Editor -> Smart keys -> Insert pair bracket`

[image]

Comment: "Insert pair bracket", 3rd from the top in your picture is what I wanted.